# SQL to add only new data

Tags: sql, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration, and in it, I make a selection in database X, where I get some information with filters, then I need to update this information in database Y. However, I need to ignore the data already recorded and just add the new data, as can i do this with a sql?

Comment: you can use merge statment or cursor to do that

Comment: Will it not weigh performance by doing or merging?

Comment: merge statment does not threaten the perfo. , also its code is cleaner

Comment: thank you very much Ismail, I will implement the merge.

Comment: please can you vote my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a merge statment for that

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27612060)

Comment: this is already an answer, and the user is happy, he is asking about a solution (not a code), and I already give it what he/she needed. So this is what an answer is about, it is not usually a code, it can be a for thought.

Answer (score 1):

if your fields names are same in tables you can use this query:

insert into Y.dbo.Y_1(fieldName)
select fieldName from X.dbo.X_1